# How can I map when I've property in my class which have default constructor to provide values automapper?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper

I want create a mapping from UserDto to User entity, please help me how can i achieve this. I've GeoLocation property in User entity how to map these properties. Can someone please give a solution with example?

I'm using AutoMapper package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/

My User Entity class:

```
public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public GeoLocation PurchaseLocationCoordinates { get; set; }
    }
```

My Dto class:

```
public class UserDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string PurchaseLocationLatitude { get; set; }

        public string PurchaseLocationLongitude { get; set; }
    }
```

GeoLocation class:

```
public class GeoLocation
    {
        public GeoLocation(double lon, double lat)
        {
            Type = "Point";
            if (lat > 90 || lat < -90) { throw new ArgumentException("A latitude coordinate must be a value between -90.0 and +90.0 degrees."); }
            if (lon > 180 || lon < -180) { throw new ArgumentException("A longitude coordinate must be a value between -180.0 and +180.0 degrees."); }
            Coordinates = new double[2] { lon, lat };
        }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
        public double[] Coordinates { get; set; }

        public double? Lat() => Coordinates?[1];
        public double? Lon() => Coordinates?[0];
    }
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<UserDto, User>();
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this code:

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<UserDto, User>()
    .ForMember(x => x.PurchaseLocationCoordinates, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model));
                cfg.CreateMap<UserDto, GeoLocation>()
                 .ForCtorParam("lon", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PurchaseLocationLongitude))
                  .ForCtorParam("lat", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PurchaseLocationLatitude));
            });
            UserDto userdto = new UserDto()
            {
                PurchaseLocationLongitude = "80.44",
                PurchaseLocationLatitude = "34.56"
            };
            IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var user = iMapper.Map<UserDto, User>(userdto);
```

Comment: No need for `double.Parse`. AM does that by default.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've accepted your answer.